# How do I execute a series of shell commands in Haskell and break on an error?

Tags: shell, haskell, monads

Suppose I have a list of `String`s representing shell commands to execute.

```
commands = ["git clone https://github.com/test/repo.git", "git checkout origin"]
```

Also, suppose I have a command, `execCommand` that takes a string, executes it as a shell command, retrieves the exit code, stdout and stderr, and, if the exit code is nonzero, returns `Just` the concatenation of stdout and stderr; otherwise, it returns `Nothing`.

Now, how would I execute that list of commands sequentially while ensuring that subsequent commands do not execute after one command yields an error?

Below is the full code for `execCommand`.

```
import System.IO
import System.Process
import System.Exit

createCommand :: String -> FilePath -> CreateProcess
createCommand command curDir =
  (shell command){std_out = CreatePipe, std_err = CreatePipe, cwd = Just curDir}

execCommand :: String -> FilePath -> IO (Maybe String)
execCommand command curDir = do
  (_, Just hout, Just herr, procHandle) <- createProcess $ createCommand command curDir
  exitCode <- waitForProcess procHandle
  stdOut   <- hGetContents hout
  stdErr   <- hGetContents herr
  if exitCode /= ExitSuccess
     then return $ Just $ concat [stdOut, stdErr]
     else return $ Nothing
```

Comment: My first question in why you would use `Either String Bool` here. That's strange for two reasons. 1. Conventionally, and because of the way its `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` instances are written, the `Right` side of either is the "all went well" side and the `Left` side is the "something went sideways" one. 2. If the weird side is always `True`, why do you need it? One option would be to use `Maybe String` instead. A more natural approach, however, would be to use `Either Int String`, so you either get the concatenated output or you get the exit code. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Another natural thing to consider (perhaps not in your application) is `Either (Int,String) String`, which either gives the standard output or gives the standard error and the exit code.   (Edit: I'm not actually sure what type an exit code is. It may well not be `Int`.)

Comment: Uhm, there's also something with the type signature. You're trying to use a monad transformer without actually using one, that might bring you lots of pain in the future. You should look up the package Either made by Edward Kmett, or ErrorT in the standard library.

Comment: @Julián, there's also `Control.Monad.Trans.Either` in `transformers`.

Comment: @dfeuer I just looked it up, and EitherT is from the either package. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0. Although a second look at the code reminds me that there's throw and catch in the standard library, using IO. So it might just be better to throw an exception when something fails.

Comment: @dfeuer I only want the output if something goes haywire. That is why I have the output in the Left column.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this might solve your problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import System.IO
import System.Process
import System.Exit
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

createCommand :: CmdSpec -> FilePath -> CreateProcess
createCommand (ShellCommand command) curDir =
  (shell command){std_out = CreatePipe, std_err = CreatePipe, cwd = Just curDir}
createCommand (RawCommand command arguments) curDir =
  (proc command arguments){std_out = CreatePipe, std_err = CreatePipe, cwd = Just curDir}

execCommand :: CmdSpec -> FilePath -> IO ()
execCommand command curDir = do
    (_, Just hout, Just herr, procHandle) <- createProcess $ createCommand command curDir
    exitCode <- waitForProcess procHandle
    when (exitCode /= ExitSuccess) $ do
        stdOut   <- hGetContents hout
        stdErr   <- hGetContents herr
        throwIO $ stdOut ++ stdErr

instance Exception String

execList :: [(CmdSpec, FilePath)] -> MaybeT IO String
execList xs = do
    out <- liftIO $ try $ mapM_ (uncurry execCommand) xs
    case out of
        Left c -> return c
        Right _ -> mzero
```

Notice that this uses FlexibleInstances. This was required for making String an instance of the Exception typeclass (the problem lies in the fact that String = [Char]). You could remove the extension by creating a new type which encloses a string and making it an instance of Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am pretty sure I figured it out. Instead of using "fancy" stuff, I fell back to good ol' recursion.

```
runCommands :: [String] -> FilePath -> IO (Maybe String)
runCommands [] _ = return Nothing
runCommands (command:rest) curDir = do
  result <- execCommand command curDir
  case result of
    Nothing  -> runCommands rest curDir
    Just err -> return $ Just err
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapM_`, which has the type

```
mapM_ :: ( (CmdSpec, FilePath)  -> ExceptT String IO ())
      ->  [(CmdSpec, FilePath)] -> ExceptT String IO ()
```

and appropriate short-circuiting behavior.